# Capture a Single Frame OpenCV-Python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

Good afternoon, I have a question about capturing a single image with OpenCV because most of the codes I have seen for videocapture get many frames until they stop but I am only interested in one as if we were taking a picture. I attach the code that I have been reviewing and I appreciate your advice.

```
import cv2

# Opens the Video file
cap= cv2.VideoCapture('C:/New/Videos/Play.mp4')
i=0
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret == False:
        break
    cv2.imwrite('kang'+str(i)+'.jpg',frame)
    i+=1

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: so? what advice do you want? your code doesn't even attempt to capture _one_ picture. that code you copied, it uses a loop, do you see that? the problem seems to be basic programming.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use a function through pyautogui like `screenshot`. In my opinion this is easier. PYAutoGUI has some of OPEN-CV built in as well.

Example:

```
import pyautogui
screenshot = pyautogui.screenshot()
screenshot.save(r'currentscreenshot.jpg')
```

Hopefully this helps! (Edit you may or may not have to install pillow, if so run `pip install pillow`.)

Comment: It sounds quite useful but it's not what I'm looking for to take a screenshot, I want to take a single image with an external camera.

Comment: Oops, I didn't realize that.